# Reference to Spreadsheet in bound-script triggered from a clickable image

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In a GAS script container-bound to a Spreadsheet and triggered from an image, as described [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#clickable_images_and_drawings_in_google_sheets), is it possible to get a reference to the Spreadsheet ?

Simple triggers get such a a reference, without the need to recur to SpreadsheetApp and its elevated permissions.

But, if we trigger a container-bound script from a clickable image, we need to recur to  SpreadsheetApp to get a reference to the Spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

It looks that you are asking if there is an event object associated to click an image used to run a script. There isn't.

The available event objects are listed on https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events

Comment: Thanks. Its just weird for me that simple triggers get an event object and these GUI options dont. Checkbox as a button will be my workaround, then